# Show that $2^n+3^n+5^n+6^n$ isn't a perfect cube, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, natural-numbers

Prove that number $A=2^n+3^n+5^n+6^n$ is not a perfect cube, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I managed to prove that 
$$2^n+3^n=5^n \mod 6$$
I also tried some particular cases.

Comment: Do you mean it isn't a perfect cube (the cube of an integer)? Every number is a cube root, as @ajotatxe says.

Comment: Someone tried to help me and he gave me a suggestion for edit, so I accepted it and i improved it, but i wanted to say perfect cube.

Answer (score 2):

By noting that

$$ (3q+r)^3 = 9(3q^3+3q^2r+qr^2) + r^3 \equiv r^3 \pmod{9}, $$

we get

$$ n^3 \equiv 0, 1, 8 \pmod{9}, \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}. $$

On the other hand, we can check that

$$ 2^n + 3^n + 5^n + 6^n \equiv 2, 7 \pmod{9}, \qquad \forall n \geq 1. $$

Comment: I'd add that we expect mod $9$ (and mod $7$, as suggested in the comments to the question) to work well because $\phi(9)=\phi(7)=6$. By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) there are very few possible $6^{\text{th}}$ powers mod $7$ or mod $9$, so there are also few possible cubes. Taking $2^n+3^n+5^n+6^n$ mod $7$ would also solve the problem.

Comment: and 14 and 18 . sixth powers can only be 0 or 1 mod 9 for example. same thing happens mod 7, so by CRT, all cubes are 0,1 mod 63. okay missed 28, and 36 doh.